# Chave primária composta com entidades no Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, entity-framework

Estou precisando fazer uma relação de chave primária composta no entity framework utilizando as próprias entidades.

```
 public class ProjetoDocumento
{ 
    public Projeto Projeto { get; set; }
    public Documento Documento { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Seria uma entidade associativa clássica, não necessariamente um caso de chave composta. Faça da seguinte forma:

```
public class ProjetoDocumento
{ 
    [Key]
    public int ProjetoDocumentoId { get; set; }
    public int ProjetoId { get; set; }
    public int DocumentoId { get; set; }

    public virtual Projeto Projeto { get; set; }
    public virtual Documento Documento { get; set; }
}
```

Adicionalmente, atualize suas entidades `Projeto` e `Documento`:

```
public class Projeto
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<ProjetoDocumento> ProjetoDocumentos { get; set; }
}

public class Documento
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<ProjetoDocumento> ProjetoDocumentos { get; set; }
}
```

Ou ainda você pode usar a Fluent API para configurar, no evento [`OnModelCreating`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) do seu contexto de dados:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Projeto>()
        .HasMany(p => p.Documentos)
        .WithMany()
        .Map(x =>
        {
            x.MapLeftKey("ProjetoId");
            x.MapRightKey("DocumentoId");
            x.ToTable("ProjetoDocumentos");
        });
```

Entretanto, essa abordagem é bem mais limitada porque não permite que você possa expandir a tabela associativa.

Neste caso as classes ficam assim:

```
public class Projeto
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Documento> Documentos { get; set; }
}

public class Documento
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Projeto> Projetos { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: é que a parte de documentos é de outro projeto e não queria deixar eles amarrados.

Comment: Um projeto pode ter N documentos, mas um documento pertence a apenas um projeto?

Comment: Não, mas a principal questão é que projeto não conhece documento diretamente, e nem deve conhecer. A entidade projeto documento estende a entidade projeto adicionando essa dependência.